# Adding additional properties to dll class

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have been given dlls for entities, service classes. I need to add additional properties to Entity in my web project. How can I do that? I cannot create new classes extending dll classes because service dll returns Entity class defined in the dlls. 
Is there any way?

thanks
Sanjivani

Comment: Well, it is ***possible*** if you're ready to decompile the dll and/or write your own `IL`... As for whether it's feasible is another story. Are you completely unable to get the original source?

Comment: I can decompile the code. This is only way I too could thought of.